# Using string.Split() in AutoMapper issue

Tags: automapper, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have an ASP .Net core application. I am simply trying to have my AutoMapper configure to convert a string comma delimited into a list of strings as per this configuration:

```cs
configuration.CreateMap<Job, JobDto>()
             .ForMember(dto => dto.Keywords, options => options.MapFrom(entity => entity.Keywords.Split(',').ToList()))
```

For some reason it does not get compiled and give me the following error:

> An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses
>   optional argument

I can't see why I am getting this error. I am pretty sure that I have done that in my other projects before without any such error.

Comment: That works for me. Try upgrading AM. A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is completely true.

Error is raised because expression tree being created is about to contain some more complex logic, like `.Split(',').ToList()`, **which is not an accessible property or method**, only top-level reflected object properties and methods are supported (like in class `MemberInfo`).

Property chaining, deep-calls (.obj1property.obj2property), extension methods are not supported by the expression trees, like in this `.ToList()` call.

My solution was like this:

```cs
// Execute a custom function to the source and/or destination types after member mapping
configuration.CreateMap<Job, JobDto>()
  .AfterMap((dto,jobDto)=>jobDto.Keywords = dto.Keywords.Split(',').ToList());
```

Comment: it seems  like it for `IQueryable`, I would like to find out how, thanks

Answer (score 25):

As error says, Split function has an optional parameter. The full signature of it is as this (**options** is optional)

```cs
public string[] Split(string separator, StringSplitOptions options = StringSplitOptions.None)
```

As you are trying to use a function with default value inside an expression tree, it gives you the error. 
To Fix it, easy, just pass on optional parameters by yourself. ( **StringSplitOptions.None** )
So, simply change it to this:

```cs
entity.Keywords.Split(',' , StringSplitOptions.None).ToList()
```

Comment: Hmm... Would be interesting to hear full story behind this - why this is needed anyway ?
I guess main idea is to simplify C# language itself, but now it's taking backing turn of making things more complex. Is there any reason for this to exists ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I do not know if it is an issue or not. Anyway, I found a workaround.

```
 CreateMap<Category, GetCategoryRest>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Words, 
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => ToWordsList(src.Words)));

 private static List<string> ToWordsList(string words)
 {
   return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(words) ? new List<string>() : words.Split(",").ToList();
 }
```

It is guaranteed that `AutoMapper` has always a `List`. Still, I'm confused. In my `Startup.cs` I define that `AutoMapper` allows null values for list.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
 cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
}
```

`Category.Words` is a `string`.
`GetCategoryRest.Words` is a `List<string>`

AutoMapper Version: 8.1.1,
AutoMapper.Microsoft.DependencyInjection: 6.1.1

Answer (score -1):

Use **.AfterMap**

```
 CreateMap<src, dto>()
                .ForMember(src =>src.Categories,options=> options.Ignore())
                .AfterMap((src, dto) => { dto.Categories.AddRange(src.Categories.Split(",").ToList()); })
                .ReverseMap()
                .ForMember(src => src.Categories, option => option.MapFrom(dto => string.Join(",", dto.Categories)));
```